# Cisco CSR1000v gives invalid_key_format error

Tags: ansible, cisco

I’m using Ansible 2.4.3 to configure CSR1000v routers. When I make any calls, including `ping`, I’m receiving an error:

`stderr=Key_load_public: invalid format`

This is using a key which was generated by AWS for the default user (ec2-user). When I SSH to the same CSR1000v and specifying the same key, it works just fine.

Sample code is below.

```
- name: Perform initial configuration on CSR1000
  hosts: all
  vars:
    ios_cfg:
      username: ec2-user
      host: csr1kv.domain.net
      ssh_keyfile: ~/.ssh/work-prod-keypair
      transport: cli
  tasks:
    - ios_facts:
        provider: '{{ios_cfg}}'
```

Comment: Do you try to run network module on the device?

Answer (score 0):

This particular problem was solved by adding ‘connection: local’.